# I want apply different width in option menu but it's take first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I want to apply  different width in different option menu but when page load my js is run and take default 25% width in all page option menu I need 25% width in header file and header include in all file so header first js is run and page option menu take also 25% width so what i do for assign different width in header and also page

he my js and css is given and I try to apply inline css it's not working and also make different class and different js but its also not working because first run header js and it's width 25% so what I do for solve this issue.

This one is my js file:

```js
! function(t) {
    var e = t('<div class="stb-select-container"><span class="selected"></span></div>'),
        n = t('<ul class="stb-select" style="display:none;"></ul>');
    t.fn.stbDropdown = function() {
        var i = t(this);
        i.hide(), i.each(function(i, a) {
            var o = e.clone(),
                s = n.clone(),
                r = t(a),
                c = r.find("option");
            r.after(o), r.appendTo(o), s.appendTo(o), c.each(function(e, n) {
                var i = t(n),
                    a = t("<li></li>"),
                    o = i.prop("attributes");
                a.prop("attributes", o), t.each(o, function(t, e) {
                    a.attr(e.name, e.value)
                }), a.append(i.text()), s.append(a)
            });
            var l, p = r.children("option").filter(function(e, n) {
                return t(n).is("[selected]")
            });
            l = 0 == p.length ? c.first() : p.first(), o.find(".selected").text(l.text()), o.on("click.stb.select", function() {
                var e = t(this),
                    n = t.grep(t(".stb-select-container"), function(n) {
                        return !e.is(t(n))
                    });
                t(n).find("ul").hide(), e.find("ul").toggle()
            }), o.on("click.stb.option", "li", function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var n = t(this),
                    i = n.parents(".stb-select-container"),
                    a = i.find("span.selected");
                a.text(n.text()), n.parents("ul").toggle();
                var o = i.find("select");
                o.val(n.attr("value")).change(), n.siblings().removeAttr("selected"), n.attr("selected", "selected")
            }), r.on("DOMNodeInserted", function(e) {
                var n = t(e.target);
                if (n.is("option")) {
                    var i = t("<li></li>"),
                        a = n.prop("attributes");
                    i.prop("attributes", a), t.each(a, function(t, e) {
                        i.attr(e.name, e.value)
                    }), i.append(n.text()), s.append(i)
                }
            }), r.on("DOMNodeRemoved", function(e) {
                var n = t(e.target);
                n.is("option") && s.find("li:contains('" + n.text() + "')").remove()
            })
        })
    }
}(jQuery);
```

```css
.stb-select-container {
    font-family: inherit;
    /*border-radius: 4px;*/
    width: 25%;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    /*border: solid thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);*/
    padding: 14px 16px;
   /* margin: 4px 8px;*/
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer
}
.stb-select-container ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.stb-select-container select {
    display: none
}
.stb-select-container .stb-select {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    left: -1px;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: solid thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    border-top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px
}
.stb-select-container span {
    opacity: .54
}
.stb-select-container::after {
    opacity: .54;
    content: "v";
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5);
    transform: scaleY(0.5)
}
.stb-select-container .stb-select li {
    opacity: .7
}
.stb-select-container .stb-select li:first-of-type {
   /* opacity: .34*/
}
.stb-select-container .stb-select li+li {
    margin-top: 10px
}

.stb-select-container .stb-select li:hover{
      color:#3EA9D8;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.stb-select-container {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    /*border-radius: 4px;*/
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
      border: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
    /*border: solid thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);*/
    padding: 12px 12px;
   /* margin: 4px 8px;*/
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer
}


}














this one is my html code
```

```html
<select name="city" id="city_result" style="height: 50px; width:100%; margin: 0px; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px white; border: none;">
    <option>Your city</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to set different  width on option menu in different page.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in guessing you are using this:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Nice-Clear-Dropdown-List-with-jQuery-and-CSS-stb-dropdown.html

There is no reason why on a page you cannot override the CSS of "width:200px or in your case "width:25%;" with inline CSS or additional styles added.

You need to identify where your problem actually is. First hard code in the container a hardcoded width. Then, if it works, put it into a CSS class and see if it is being applied. Then, if it works, you can choose to implement this in JS, or with additional styling for that page, or in any way you choose really.

There are simply too many ways to achieve what you want, but the method you employ depends entirely on you, your system, your methodology and your project guidelines/objectives.

Comment: i cant't override css in my page i have a three option menu in my page and i want different size option menu but i can't